# Async rewrite of sync code performs 20 times slower in loops

Tags: c#, performance, async-await

I'm trying not to panic here, so please, bear with me! :S

I've spent a considerable amount of time rewriting a big chunk of code from sync (i.e. thread-blocking) to async (i.e. C# 6+). The code in question runs inside an ASP.NET application and spans everything from low-level ADO.NET DB access to higher-level unit-of-work pattern, and finally a custom async HTTP handler for public API access - the full server-side stack, so to speak. The primary purpose of the rewrite wasn't optimization, but untangling, general clean-up, and bringing the code up to something that resembles a modern and deliberate design. Naturally, optimization gain was implicitly assumed.

Everything in general is great and I'm very satisfied with the overall quality of the new code, as well as the improved scalability it's shown so far in the last couple of weeks of real-world tests. The CPU and memory loads on the server have fallen drastically!

So what's the problem, you might ask?

Well, I've recently been tasked with optimizing a simple data import that is still utilizing the old sync code. Naturally, it didn't take me long before I tried changing it to the new async code-base to see what would happen.

Given everything, the import code is quite simple. It's basically a loop that reads items from a list that's been previously read into memory, adds each of them individually to a unit of work, and saves it to a SQL database by means of an INSERT statement. After the loop is done, the unit of work is committed, which makes the changes permanent (i.e. the DB transaction is committed as well).

The problem is that the new code takes about *20 times as long* as the old one, when the expectation was quite the opposite! I've checked and double-checked and there is no obvious overhead in the new code that would warrant such sluggishness.

To be specific: the old code is able to import 1100 items/sec steadily, while the new one manages 40 items/sec AT BEST (on average, it's even less, because the rate is falling slightly over time)! If I run the same test over a VPN, so that the network cost outweighs everything else, the throughputs is somewhere along 25 items/sec for sync and 20 for async.

I've read about multiple cases here on SO which report a 10-20% slowdown when switching from sync to async in similar situations and I was prepared to deal with that for tight loops such as mine. But a 20-fold penalty in a non-networked scenario?! That's completely unacceptable!

What is my best course of action here? How do I tackle this unexpected problem?

**UPDATE**

I've run the import under a profiler, as suggested.

I'm not sure what to make of the results, though. It would seem that the process spends more than 80% of its time just... waiting. See for yourselves:

[image: Profiler report]

The 14% spent inside the custom HTTP handler corresponds to the `IDataReader.Read` which is a consequence of a tiny remainder of the old sync API. This is still subject to optimization and is likely to be reduced in the near future. Regardless, it's dwarfed by the `WaitAny` cost, which definitely isn't there in the all-sync version!

What's curious is that the report isn't showing any direct calls from my code to `WaitAny`, which makes me think this is probably part of the async/await infrastructure. Am I wrong in this conclusion? I kind of hope I am!

What worries me is that I might be reading this all wrong. I know that async costs are much harder to reason about than single-threaded costs. In the end, the `WaitAny` might be nothing more than the equivalent of the "Sytem Idle Process" on Windows - an artificial representation of the CPU infrastructure that reflects a free percentage of the CPU resource.

Can anyone shed some light here for me, please?

Comment: You'd need to provide a sample of the section of code, via a [mcve], that you believe comparably to be causing the difference in timing.

Comment: If you expect async code to be faster than synchronous multi threaded one then you need to revisit the async concept. Async will be always slower than normal code, the context switching, task planning and so on will make your code a lot slower. But, in counterpart, your server will be able to handle a ton more of parallel tasks.

Comment: @gravity No need to "believe", the first step in this situation should be run a profiler and know for sure what parts are slow and use that to make the MCVE. Gusman, the OP knows it will be slower, he was expecting a 10-20% slowdown not a 20x slowdown he is currently seeing

Comment: Are you perhaps using synchronous code to access the database? Databases are *a lot* faster when processing transactions in parallel, which is what happens with threads. If you're accessing the database synchronously, you're basically using just one *database* thread for all database access, which can explain the drastic slowdown.

Comment: @gravity: I'm doing this right now, thanks! I'm going to need some time to interpret the results, though.

Comment: @zmbq: No, all my new DB code uses async calls on DbConnection and DbCommand objects. The old code, however, DID use the sync calls - and still it was 20x faster!

Comment: Instead of 1000 items being 1000 separate database actions, try batching.

Comment: @Ben: I'm aware of this optimization. It doesn't address the difference, though. The import in question has actually been simplified to pure INSERTs for purposes of testing. The actual import is unpredictable - it may involve INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, as well as no-ops. The number of DB calls is beside the point. In fact, a non-optimized 1-DB-call-per-operation approach helps to emphasize the disproportionate cost of async here, I believe!

Comment: Asking about performance of database code with no batching is like asking about performance of code with compiler optimizations turned off.

Comment: @Ben: Again, I'm aware. :) But perhaps you missed the fact that I'm comparing *relative* performance of two pieces of code that basically only differ in their use of sync vs. async. The absolute numbers might be better with batching, I agree, but the relative difference surely won't be any smaller! I'm trying to determine why THAT difference exists and why it's so big! That's the part that is making no sense to me...

Comment: "the relative difference surely won't be any smaller" -- like most things performance related, you should not believe such a thing without evidence.  I strongly suspect that the relative difference will indeed get much smaller.  If you have 10ms of work and 2ms of wait, 10000 times, and the wait increases to 5ms, that's a large relative increase.  If you have 10000ms of work and 5ms wait for the batch, repeated 10 times, and the wait increases to 50ms, that's a tiny relative increase, possibly lost in the measurement error.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what async db access API are you using. According to the explanation, the only one I can think of is the `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, is that correct? Also what's the type of the target database?

Comment: Should you maybe create benchmarks for sync and async DB access with https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet to either confirm or deny that the bottleneck is data access? And post code on github so we can look at it and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Neither `IDataReader.Read` nor `Task.WaitAll` are asynchronous (`ReadAsync` / `Task.WhenAll` would be asynchronous). This leads me to believe you're probably comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm glad you chimed in! That was one of the first things I noticed myself, as well! :) But the question is: how *would* a truly async call even register to a profiler? AFAIU, an efficient async method would cost ~0 CPU cycles and therefore NOT be flagged by the profiler. The only calls that would be flagged are the ones that block a thread, no? As for the apples and oranges, I think you might be right... I've since established that my slowdown probably isn't related to async at all. The problematic method just wasn't exposed by the profiler. Still looking into that... :(

Comment: It's *possible* to track async operations; e.g., by default ASP.NET supports this for async requests. You would need to define your own ETW start/end events and raise them appropriately. It's a pain, and doesn't integrate fully seamlessly with the VS profiler (as of the last time I had to do it - a couple years ago), but it is doable.